# Install Nokogiri on Windows w/ System Libraries

Tags: ruby, windows, nokogiri, libxml2, libxslt

I am attempting to install Nokogiri 1.7.1 on a 64-bit windows machine without internet capabilities. I downloaded the Nokogiri gem and the necessary libraries (libxml2, libxslt, iconv, zlib) and transferred them to the internet-less machine. I am now trying to get the gem install to run correctly with this command:

```
gem install --local <path to nokogiri-1.7.1.gem> -- --use-system-libraries \
    --with-xml2-lib=<path to xml2path>\lib --with-xml2-include=<path to xml2path>\include\libxml2 \
    --with-xslt-lib=<path to xsltpath>\lib --with-xslt-include=<path to xsltpath>\include\libxslt \
    --with-iconv-dir=<path to iconv> --with-zlib-dir=<path to zlib>
```

But I keep getting the same error:

```
The compiler failed to generate an executable file. You have to install development tools first.
```

along with the same messages everyone else gets when they can't build Nokogiri. I am using libxml2 2.9.2 and libxslt 1.1.28

Comment: nokogiri usually supplies Windows gems that are "fat" and include the compiled portions already included, so the fact that it's asking for build tools might be thrown off by the other flags.  have you simply tried `gem install --local <path to gem>`?

Comment: Note that, I believe 1.7.1 only supports Ruby versions less than 2.4 - is that what you're running?

Comment: What version of ruby are you using?

Comment: I am using ruby 2.5.0

Comment: @Joe I have tried `gem install --local <path>` but I receive the same errors as specified in the question

Comment: I think you need to try a newer version of Nokogiri with ruby 2.5.0.